# Processor energy management in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, power-management, intel-atom

What does it mean to set the cpu's top performance at 60% under a Windows 7 power plan?

I have an intel atom processor at 1.66Ghz, does that mean it will act as underclocked at 1.00Ghz? Or are there other factors to consider?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Very simply: It means that **Windows will *try* to tell your CPU to lower the clock to 1.00 Ghz**.

But that's only assuming your CPU supports it; if it doesn't, it'll clock down to the nearest value.

---

You can use different tools to see how much your computer is actually clocking down:

- (Built-in, GUI): Resource Monitor: Go to Task Manager->Performance->Resource monitor, and you can see the `% Maximum Frequency` that it's displaying.
- (Built-in, Console): Go to the command prompt and type in `WMIC` and then `CPU`, and take a look at the `CurrentClockSpeed` and `CurrentVoltage` columns.
- (Third-party, GUI): Download [Speccy](http://www.piriform.com/speccy), it'll give you more information than you ever even wanted to know. :)

[image: Speccy]

Comment: I love how this site punishes broad questions, but not broad answers (linking me to documentation) This is by far the most specific question, it might not be that informative but makes me feel better somehow. But don't worry, Everyone gets a point from me when you answer my questions. Enjoy your fifty reps Mehrdad!

Comment: @questionBot: Haha thank you. =) By the way, you can check your clock speed by going to Resource Monitor (from Task Manager->Performance) and looking at the "% Maximium Frequency" -- that should give you an idea of what's actually happening.

Comment: Ah there, I could see the frequency cut when I unplugged my laptop dow to 60 percent, it's not terribly specific but at least I know the feature is responding. Thanks agains Mehrdad, you nailed my question with that comment.

Comment: @questionBot: Glad it helped. Another (more) specific way is to go to the command prompt and type `WMIC` and, when it goes into the console, type in `CPU`, and then take a look at the `CurrentClockSpeed` and `CurrentVoltage` that gets printed. (You'll need to scroll horizontally. To quit, type in `Exit` twice to get out of WMIC and then the command prompt.) Those are the most specific numbers you can get from Windows tools. You might also find [Speccy](http://www.piriform.com/speccy) helpful, since it shows a lot of info like this as well.

Comment: Holy crap it shows it! I can see it runs at 999Ghz with my configuration, this is excellent. You deserved  100 rep for that Mehrdad. Try to complement your answer with those comments, maybe more people will vote for it.

Comment: @questionBot: Haha thanks. :) And lol, 999 GHz? That's a **really** nice laptop (mine is only ~2 GHz), I wanna buy it; how much are you selling that for? :P

Comment: oops sorry, it was Mhz

Comment: @questionBot: Yeah, I got it, it was just funny. :)

Answer (score 2):

My answer concerns rather the power-management features of Windows 7, and not the hardware.

Toshiba's [How to handle the power managment features of Windows 7](https://web.archive.org/web/20110507143435/http://aps2.toshiba-tro.de/kb0/HTD12017W0001R01.htm) describes the Advanced power settings in the Power Options applet of the Control Panel:

> **Processor power management**
>
> **Minimum processor state**
>
> Specifies the lower limit of CPU
> performance, as a percentage of the
> full potential performance of the CPU.
> Higher values promote higher
> performance (depending on CPU
> utilization), at the expense of
> greater power consumption.
>
> **Maximum processor state**
>
> Specifies the upper limit of CPU
> performance, as a percentage of the
> full potential performance of the CPU.
> Higher values promote higher
> performance (depending on CPU
> utilization), at the expense of
> greater power consumption. The minimum
> and maximum processor state values are
> essentially percentage of the maximum
> clock rate for the CPU, though other
> factors may be involved. For further
> details, see Microsoft's document
> Processor Power Management in Windows
> 7.

The mentioned Microsoft document can be found here : [Processor Power Management in Windows 7](https://web.archive.org/web/20101229192934/https://download.microsoft.com/download/8/5/4/854f66b6-8c09-4f8a-986e-38e9ebac1677/windows7_power_management_whitepaper.pdf), which also mentions :

**Core Parking**
helps improve the energy efficiency of a system by dynamically
scaling the number of logical processors that are in use based on workload.

**Processor Clocking Control** 
Windows is not in direct control of the processor’s
performance state, but instead communicates its performance state preference to
the underlying platform hardware. This is used for fine-tuning hardware systems such as Intel's SpeedStep.

Answer (score 1):

Windows is using Intel's SpeedStep feature to do this. Intel has a [full explanation](https://web.archive.org/web/20141222225151/http://www.intel.com/support/processors/sb/CS-028855.htm) of how SpeedStep works on their website. The [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SpeedStep) is also very informative. I don't know what more specific information you're looking for than what Sandeep already told you, but one of those sources likely has it. Intel's [Atom Processor info page](https://web.archive.org/web/20110318040043/http://www.intel.com/products/processor/atom/index.htm) might also have the info you're looking for somewhere in their technical documents.

Comment: I didn't know it had a name that SpeedStep thing.

Comment: @questionBot: AMD's is called `PowerNow!`.

Answer (score 0):

Most if not all CPUs have power saving features, Intel with Speedstep and AMD with Cool n Quiet, which can be enabled/disabled in the BIOS (most likely not being able to be changed in laptop BIOS)

setting your processor at a max of 60% in the speed setting will set it to 60% of the actual speed of the CPU.

Each stepping from 0-100% has voltage changes, therefore sticking your CPU to 60% will underclock your CPU and also provide a lower voltage than used in the max CPU clock thus saving power.

Looking here: intel.ly/6Gm0EV  -- It shows that it's voltage ranges are 0.800V-1.175V I have tried having a look around the net but I can't seem to give you exact information about the steppings of speedstep. You can try booting into a live ubuntu CD and entering "cat /proc/cpuinfo" into a terminal to see what it outputs.

Hope that helps.

Comment: I'm sorry Sandeep, now that I think about it, I need more specific information about this, You see, your answer tells my exact assumptions about this matter. I need objective information like numbers, rates, watts, etcetera.

Comment: The only way I can tell you specific information about the CPU Clock, Voltage and power consumption is by knowing your CPUs Make and Model.

Comment: An Atom N450 Pineview.

Comment: Looking here: http://intel.ly/6Gm0EV -- It shows that it's voltage ranges are 0.800V-1.175V I have tried having a look around the net but I can't seem to give you exact information about the steppings of speedstep. You can try booting into a live ubuntu CD and entering "cat /proc/cpuinfo" into a terminal to see what it outputs.

Comment: @Sandeep: I thought AMD's was called `PowerNow!`?

Comment: Sandeep edit your question so you can get a point!

Comment: @Mehrdad you're right, I was thinking of the Desktop CPUs.
@questionBot I have edited the answer with the info I told you about in the comments.